# Mapping interface between POJOs and DTOs

Tags: java, interface, dto

Following up on this question [DTO interfaces for implementing web service integration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64574/dto-interfaces-for-implementing-web-service-integration) I came up with this implementation.

Data Transfer Object interface following a java.util.Map protocol. The implementation uses Guava's ForwardingMap.

```
public interface Dto<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {}

public class DtoImpl<K, V> extends ForwardingMap<K, V> implements Dto<K, V> {

    private final Map<K, V> delegate;

    @Override
    protected Map<K, V> delegate() {
        return this.delegate;
    }

    private DtoImpl(final Map<K, V> map) {
        this.delegate = map;
    }

    public static <K, V> Dto<K, V> of(final Map<K, V> map) {
        return new DtoImpl<K, V>(map);
    }
}
```

Mapper interface between a type T and a Dto.

```
public interface Mapper<T> {

    public <K, V> Dto<K, V> toDto(T obj);

    public <K, V> T fromDto(Dto<K, V> dto, Class<T> clazz);
}

public class MapperImpl<T> implements Mapper<T> {

    public <K, V> Dto<K, V> toDto(T obj) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<K, V> map = objectMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
        return DtoImpl.of(map);
    }

    public <K, V> T fromDto(Dto<K, V> dto, Class<T> clazz) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        T obj = objectMapper.convertValue(dto, clazz);
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Comments and improvements on this implementation are welcome!
Is it worth it to define the Mapper interface with something like interface `Mapper<T, K, V>`? Ideally I would like to say `interface Mapper<T, S extends Dto<K, V>>` but this is not possible or is it?

Answer (score 1):

`public interface Dto<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {}` why don't you use simply a `Map`? Again, it is the same discussion related to marker interfaces we already had in your original question.

I'd define `Mapper` in the following way:

```
public interface Mapper<T, K, V> {
    public Dto<K, V> toDto(T obj);
    public T fromDto(Dto<K, V> dto);
}
```

I don't understand the reason why you need `MapperImpl`. What you need are **concrete** classes imlementing your interface for your specific types.

Imagine you want to map a `Date` to a `Map<String,Integer>`. You need something like this:

```
class DateMapper implements Mapper<Date, String, Integer>
{
    public Dto<String, Integer> toDto(Date date)
    {
        Dto<String, Integer> dto = new Dto<String, Integer>();
        dto.put("Day", date.Day());
        dto.put("Month", date.Month());
        dto.put("Year", date.Year());
    }

    public Date fromDto(Dto<String, Integer> dto)
    {
        return new Date(dto.get("Year"), dto.get("Month"), dto.get("Day"));
    }
}
```

I think that at this point you might be thinking at how you could obtain an instance of `DateMapper`. I think you should use some sort of factory or build it using reflection depending on what is better in your use case.

Comment: I just found out that my Dto interface is an anti-pattern http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02216/index.html. In your implementation you are programming against a concrete type Dto (which you didn't provide an implementation for) but isn't it better to code against interfaces? I guess your intention is to replace Dto by java.util.Map.

Comment: The intention of my MapperImpl was to provide a skeletal implementation of the Mapper interface that can map a generic POJO to a Map using a library such as Jackson.  It should be able to map most value objects automatically like the DateMapper you showed.

Comment: @dmz73 Apart from your `Dto` interface being bad or not, it does not implement the antipattern that link talks about. Look at [the specific example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02216/index.html#listing1).

Comment: @mariosangiorgio *I'd define Mapper in the following way:* You need to elaborate why your definition is better.